# Github login error: That account is an organization, you can't log in to it. Try your personal account instead

Tags: github

When I login github with my gmail address, it says "That account is an organization, you can't log in to it. Try your personal account instead."

I don't know what's wrong with my account.

Does it mean my account is in an organization? If it is, how to exit that organization?

Or I guess I have used that email address register an organization, how to remove that organization?

Thanks very much.

Comment: This is a programming Q and A site, not github support..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Enjoy your stay! Meanwhile, please improve your question by posting what steps you've taken so far to research or resolve your programming-related issue.

Comment: This is a question for the GitHub support: https://help.github.com/contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got an organization ther:

https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations

Administrator(s) are assigned to an organization and he/she/them manage it. You must to login using your administrator account credentials to manage your organization.

Comment: Yes, I login with my another account, I found I indeed used that gmail account register an organization.

Comment: It really seems strange, why I cannot create new account with that organization. Thnaks anyway.